# Which Windows 7 Service(s) are responsible for home network folder sharing?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I setup a few computers to share folders from their desktops. I then can access the shared folders from a single computer.

However, recently I disabled almost all of the services running on my "single computer" in a foolish attempt to increased computer performance. I must have disabled the one that allows sharing folders across my home network to operate.

There is a bewildering list of services listed in Component Services. I'm not sure which ones are the critical ones. Here are some screen shots to show you what I mean. First up are the ones set to Automatic (delayed) start up:

[image]

And next these are all disabled. Presumably whatever I switched off that is causing this issue should be in this list:

[image]

A weird thing (at least to me) is that I went through and turned on anything and everything that remotely sounds like it might be controlling networks, etc. it still didn't work. And there are hundreds of services. As a newbie to this I'd rather ask the experts here at superuser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also comes down to services related to general and Homenetwork networking. 
But the list of dependencies is too long. Maybe you could crowd source this list of absolute dependencies here. My crow-sourcing contribution starts with:

- The Server and Workstation service is important.
- Then you have the File and Printer sharing in the Network and Sharing Center.

When the list is complete, you can mark the last list as the answer.

**Exciting times ahead :-)**

Comment: Yes! Enabling Workstation service did the trick.

Comment: Apparently anything with "SMB PROTOCOL" listed in the service description should be enabled.